# Analytical solution of the following Neumann problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I may need some help for finding the exact solution for the following Newmann problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated:
Consider the Neumann problem
$$ -\bigtriangleup u + u = \cos(\pi x) - \cos(\pi y) \text{ in } \Omega$$
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega $$
where $\Omega$ is the unit square [0,1]$\times$[0,1]

I tried $u = a \cos(\pi x) + b \sin(\pi y) + c$ but I don't think it satisfies the boundary condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try a guess solution
$$u(x,y)=a\cos(\pi x)+b\cos(\pi y)+c\sin(\pi x)+d\sin(\pi y)$$
You will find that
$$-\Delta u+u=(1+\pi^2)u$$
So taking $a=-b=\frac{1}{1+\pi^2}$ yields
$$(-\Delta u+u)(x,y)=\cos(\pi x)-\cos(\pi y)$$
As for boundary conditions, it turns out that this guess satisfies them:
\begin{aligned}
(+1,0)\cdot(\nabla u)(+1,y)=0\\ (-1,0)\cdot(\nabla u)(-1,y)=0 \\ (0,+1)\cdot (\nabla u)(x,+1)=0 \\ (0,-1)\cdot (\nabla u)(x,-1)=0
\end{aligned}
I'll let you check these for yourself.